# How do I call an intent in Retrofit Callback?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, retrofit

I want to display a new activity on success callback of my WebService called by Retrofit.
And I have difficulties to find examples on how to use Retrofit callback result to launch new activity.
Is that a good way to do it ? Do I have to clean up some stuff before?

```
public void validate(View view) {
    RetrofitWebServices.getInstance().webserviceMethod(params,new Callback<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public void success(MyObject object, Response response) {
            Intent barIntent = new Intent(FooActivity.this, BarActivity.class);
            startActivity(barIntent);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can implement `Callback` with weak reference to `Context`

```
public class MyCallback implements Callback<MyObject> {

    WeakReference<Context> mContextReference;

    public MyCallback(Context context) {
        mContextReference = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void success(MyObject arg0, Response arg1) {
        Context context = mContextReference.get();
        if(context != null){
            Intent barIntent = new Intent(FooActivity.this, BarActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(barIntent);
        } else {
            // TODO process context lost
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError arg0) {
        // TODO process error
    }

}
```

Just remember - this solution will not work if `Context` lost occurred while request in progress but you may don't worry about potential memory leak which may be if you keep strong reference to `Context` object.

Comment: Thank you. I use this pattern for all my webservices calls.But is it the correct way to do it? Does it always have to be an asynchronous call in android?

Comment: Since Android forces you to perform network requests in separate thread this mechanism will always be asynchronous - explicitly or implicitly. Using Retrofit you can implement both synchronous (using return value) and asynchronous flow (using callbacks). Just remember - in first case you must take care of threading by yourself. I can't guarantee that this callback approach is best way to achieve your goal but I'm afraid there is no absolutely reliable and leak-safe method which allow you to keep context reference alive.

Answer (score 2):

Hi have a solution that seems easier: use the `getApplicationContext()` function.

I am not 100% sure it is OK, but in my case it works as expected.

Your code would be:

```
public void validate(View view) {
    RetrofitWebServices.getInstance().webserviceMethod(params,new Callback<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public void success(MyObject object, Response response) {
            Intent barIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BarActivity.class);
            startActivity(barIntent);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```