# Null pointer in retrofit callback when call getActivity

Tags: android, fragment, retrofit

I'm using retrofit for fetching data from resource. But think my architecture is wrong.
So, i have an fragment with listview, for example.

In onCreateView after UI setup i calls  API method(async). That returns list of models i need to setup my listview adapter.

Thats i do in callback

```
 private Callback<List<User>> mUsersCallback = new Callback<List<User>>() {
    @Override
    public void success(List<User> users, Response response) {
        mLoadingLayout.hideLoading();
        mPeopleAdapter = new PeopleAdapter(getActivity(), users);
        lvPeople.setAdapter(mPeopleAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        mLoadingLayout.hideLoading();
        Log.d("get users", error.getUrl() + "  " + error.toString());
    }
};
```

In this part i sometimes get NPE when call getActivity();
How to do it on right way?

Comment: posting log might help

Comment: @KaranMer there is no need to log, really. It just NPE when call getActivity()
I suppose, it is bad to getActivity in callback of async method

Answer (score 1):

Your activity has been destroyed during the call, when you try to get it in your callback, it may be null.

Simply check if activity is not null and if null ignore the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your own Callback class and there pass your Activity or Context by constructor.

Similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25665521/2399340